Why does TypeScript handle differently a conditional function type and the same function type with only a conditional return type?
I have two function types which I expected to be equivalent, but they behave differently.
These are the types:
type MatchT<T extends {id: string}, M> =
    [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
        ? [T] extends [X]
            ? (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M>
            : (t: T, m: M) => never
        : (t: T, m: M) => never;

and:
type MatchT<T extends {id: string}, M> = (t: T, m: M) =>
    [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
        ? [T] extends [X]
            ? Ret<T, M>
            : never
        : never;

The difference is that in the first case the whole function type is inside a conditional, while in the second, only the return type is.
MatchT is used to re-type a function with type <T>(t: T, map: TyMap<T>): Ret<T, TyMap<T>> into one with type <T, X>(t: T, map: TyMap<X>): Ret<T, TyMap<X>> as long as T is a subtype of X. (These types aren't valid in TS, but they're short and give a good intuition on what I'm trying to do).
The first version works as I'd expect, while the second one fails and returns never. Experimentally I noticed that [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>] evaluates to false, but only in the second version of MatchT.
Why do the two types give me different results?
You can play with a fully working example on the playground: https://tsplay.dev/NVX7MW. The namespace test_1 uses the first version of the MatchT I posted here, while test_2 uses the second one. Otherwise you can find the example code here:
type A = {id: "A", a: number}
type B = {id: "B", b: string}

type TyMap<T extends {id: string}> = {
    [K in T['id']]: (x: T & {id: K})=>unknown
}
type Ret<T extends {id: string}, M extends TyMap<T>> = ReturnType<M[T['id']]>;
function match<T extends {id: string}, M extends TyMap<T>>(t: T, map: M): Ret<T, M> {
    const f = (map as Record<string,unknown>)[t.id] as (x: T) => Ret<T, M>;
    return f(t);
}


declare const a: A, ab: A | B;


namespace test_1 {
    const matchT = <T extends {id: string}, M>(t: T, m: M) => {
        return (match as MatchT<T, M>)(t, m);
    }
    type MatchT<T extends {id: string}, M> =
        [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
            ? [T] extends [X]
                ? (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M>
                : (t: T, m: M) => never
            : (t: T, m: M) => never;

    const wrap = <T extends A|B>(t: T) => {
        return matchT(t, {A: a => a.a, B: b => b.b} satisfies TyMap<A|B>);
    }

    const a1 = wrap(a);
    //    ^?
    const ab1 = wrap(ab);
    //    ^?
}

namespace test_2 {
    const matchT = <T extends {id: string}, M>(t: T, m: M) => {
        return (match as MatchT<T, M>)(t, m);
    }
    type MatchT<T extends {id: string}, M> = (t: T, m: M) =>
        [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
            ? [T] extends [X]
                ? Ret<T, M>
                : never
            : never;

    const wrap = <T extends A|B>(t: T) => {
        return matchT(t, {A: a => a.a, B: b => b.b} satisfies TyMap<A|B>);
    }

    const a1 = wrap(a);
    //    ^?
    const ab1 = wrap(ab);
    //    ^?
}


How come the tags typescript-generics and conditional-types have been removed? I don't mind, but would like to understand it in order to avoid misusing tags in the future.

Oops! I posted the wrong link. I fixed it now. The example is as minimal as I could get it.

This is still pretty complicated, but the issue is that it handles calling such a function type when it is still generic differently. If the function type is conditional, the compiler has to widen it to call it, and matchT is of type <T extends { id: string; }, M>(t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M>, essentially skipping the check that fails. If only the return is conditional, then the call can preserve the generics and you get <T extends { id: string; }, M>(t: T, m: M) => [M] extends [TyMap<infer X extends { id: string; }>] ? [T] extends [X] ? Ret<T, M> : never : never, which (more...)

(...continued) behaves differently because it checks more things. Does that fully address the question as asked? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I still think I don't understand. Sure, the compiler needs to evaluate the conditional at different points (in order to call for the first case, and only when the result is needed for the second). But it's still not clear to me why one would work and the other one fails (either in general, or in my specific case).

If you have a value of a generic conditional type and try to do something with it, the compiler generally has to try to evaluate it and will do so imperfectly because it doesn't know what the generics will be. For your first case, the compiler makes the imperfect assumption that it's of type (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M>. That "works" because the check that fails is completely skipped. Not sure how else to phrase this. What, specifically, is still confusing here?

I'm still confused by which one is "the check that fails". Experimentally I've seen that [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>] evaluates to false in the second case. Is that one the check you're talking about? I wouldn't expect it to fail, since the argument I pass as M does extend TyMap<A | B>. Besides I don't understand how it could be "skipped", since X gets resolved successfully.

At last, I also wonder whether I can rely on the code in test_1 (the one that succeeds, although it shouldn't, according to what you said), or if I should expect it to break in the future, if improvements to TypeScript make the compiler able to evaluate the checks more precisely? I'd love to know whether it's possible to achieve what I'm trying to in a better way, that doesn't rely on TS' imperfect knowledge; but maybe I should open a new question for this?

• Yes, that's the check I'm talking about. Why it fails is outside the scope of the question as asked, which is about why there's a difference of behavior for the two forms. That has everything to do with trying to call a generic conditional function and very little to do with the specifics of your conditional type. (more...)

(...continued)  • It gets "skipped" and X is not resolved "successfully" because when you call a function of type [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>] ? [T] extends [X] ? (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M> : (t: T, m: M) => never  : (t: T, m: M) => never; with generic M and T, the compiler just prematurely "resolves" T and M to their constraints more or less, and guesses the final type of the function. You shouldn't call functions this way, because the details of how the guess happens are compiler-impl dependent and not documented well. (more...)

(...continued) • No, you cannot rely on test_1 because it's only accidentally working for you. You should use the test_2 form, and if you don't understand why it doesn't work, you can open a new question to ask why that check fails.  Again, this is out of scope for this question. • At this point I can either write up an answer explaining this as well as I can, or disengage. Please let me know which you'd like to see.

OK, thanks. You fully answered everything I couldn't understand.

For any specific T and M, your two versions of MatchT<T, M> will evaluate to the same type.  But when T and M are generic, different things can happen, because at various stages TypeScript needs to decide whether to defer evaluation of a type with a generic keeping T or M as-is (which is always "correct" but that means the type is likely to be a useless opaque blob) or whether to try to guess what it will evaluate to based on some heuristics like widening T and M to their constraints (which gives you some more specific type to use, but will not always be accurate).

In both cases you have a function match of type Match<T, M> and you call it with arguments of type T and M respectively.  When Match<T, M> is defined as
type MatchT<T extends { id: string }, M> = (t: T, m: M) =>
    [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
    ? [T] extends [X]
    ? Ret<T, M>
    : never
    : never;

then this looks like a single function type whose parameters are of type T and M. This function is callable directly, and the return type is [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>] ? [T] extends [X] ? Ret<T, M> : never : never; There's no need for the compiler to try to evaluate T and M in order to produce this result. This conditional type stays deferred. This is most likely to be correct (and if you don't like the behavior, it's because your type isn't correct in some way, not because the function call behaved incorrectly.)
On the other hand, when Match<T, M> is defined as
type MatchT<T extends { id: string }, M> =
    [M] extends [TyMap<infer X>]
    ? [T] extends [X]
    ? (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M>
    : (t: T, m: M) => never
    : (t: T, m: M) => never;

then this looks like you're trying to call something which isn't a single function type. In order to proceed, the compiler needs to make some guesses about T and M. The particulars are not very well documented here, but what you get out looks like (t: T, m: M) => Ret<T, M> (in my research you get something like ((...args: [t: T, m: M] | [t: T, m: M]) => Ret<T, M> | never), which is equivalent to that).  And so the function return type is just Ret<T, M> no matter what.  It's no longer conditional on T and M.  This isn't an accurate representation of what would actually happen at runtime; it's a simplification. But without such a simplification, TypeScript could only shrug and say that match would be uncallable completely.

That accounts for the difference in behavior.  I would say that you never want to call a generic conditional function. Nor do you want to write out your own complicated conditional types if you can avoid them. I'd probably prefer MatchT to be of the form
type MatchT<T extends { id: string }, M> = (t: T, m: M) =>
    Ret<T, Extract<M, TyMap<T>>>;

using the Extract utility type to convince the compiler to allow Ret<T, M> (if M is indeed assignable to TyMap<T>, then Extract<M, TyMap<T>> will be M. If not, it will probably be never).
But these concerns are out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't digress further.
Playground link to code

Thanks. The explanation is very clear. Also thanks for suggesting a better type to use instead of mine.
